Need assistance with Awall policy configuration for IPSEC on Alpine Linux
I am using Awall on Alpine Linux. I could not get any technical document for writing Filter and IPSec zone.
IPsec tunnel is established, but I could not send ICMP packets (ping) between two endpoints.
The following filter is added in AWALL config (IPSec tunnel is established)
{
  "in": ["internet", "_fw"],
  "out": ["_fw","internet"],
  "service": "ipsec",
  "action": "accept",
  "log":"info"
}

Can anybody show me how to pass traffic through IPSec tunnel?
